# Awk - Rename the output file name same as input file name after processing input file

Tags: awk, rename

I have one input file `ABC.txt` and one output `DEF.txt`. After the `ABC` is processed and created output, I want to rename `ABC.txt` to `ABC.orig` and `DEF` to `ABC.txt`.

Currently when I am doing this, it is giving me an error as it cannot read and write to the same file.

**Example:**

```
awk ' $1=="01" { print $2 $4}' ABC.txt > DEF.txt
mv ABC.txt ABC.orig
mv DEF.txt ABC.txt
```

Comment: `mv ABC.txt ABC.orig; awk '...' ABC.orig > ABC.txt`

Comment: What is your question?  Is there a problem with the code you have now?  The symptom you are describing does not manifest with the example code you show us.

Comment: ... though `Awk` needs to be lowercase and `01=="01"` is never true.

Comment: Might you show the error message reported?

Comment: It does not shoe the error message but does not process file either.

Comment: If i change mv DEF.txt ABC.txt to mv DEF.txt XYZ. Script works fine.